# getAdapterPosition in onCreateViewHolder is always "-1"

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

in many questions, people say "call OnClickListener in onCreateViewHolder. you don't need call OnClickListener each item in onBindViewHolder"

```
@Override
  public Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(itemLayout, parent, false);
     final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(v);

     holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Log.d(TAG, "position = " + holder.getAdapterPosition());
         }
     });
     return new Viewholder(v);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(final BoardListViewHolder holder, int position) {

  }
```

but in Logcat, always show "position = -1"

this is not correct.

why i should call onClickListener in onCreateViewHolder?

Comment: have the click listener in your viewholder

Comment: share your ViewHolder  class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> getAdapterPosition in onCreateViewHolder is always “-1”

You should **`return holder`**  instead of **`new Viewholder(v)`** .

**Code Structure**

```
@Override
  public Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(itemLayout, parent, false);
     final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(v);

     holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Log.d(TAG, "position = " + holder.getAdapterPosition());
         }
     });
     return holder;
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(final BoardListViewHolder holder, int position) {

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're returning a new `ViewHolder` instead of the one you set the click listener on.

Instead of `return new Viewholder(v)`, you should `return holder;`

A clearer way of setting click listeners can be

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.layout_item, parent, false));
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView image;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do what you need to do. getAdapterPosition() is useful here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`onCreateViewHolder` is used to inflate the layout resource only and you shouldn't put any methods related to your holder items here.

Instead, you have to use `onBindViewHolder` to get the value of `holder.getAdapterPosition` or set `onClickListeners` etc. there.

Comment: I thought I knew why, but it did not finish well .... I did not know it properly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First `return holder` instead of `return new Viewholder(v)`
You can have `OnClickListener` in your `ViewHolder` and get position by `getAdapterPosition()`

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "position = " + getAdapterPosition());
                //do your stuff here


            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment!
because wrong return type, i couldn't get correct position  :(